# Can I download Web application client dynamically inside android apk and launch?

Tags: android, node.js, angularjs, cordova, web

Is there any procedure or mechanism under which I can download on the fly, full web-application inside my android apk (web application converted by cordova) and show it in a webview ?

I have a heavy web-application client (Angularjs Application) which is converted into android application (apk) using cordova. Every web-application client version has a corresponding server version installed in a server at customer location. So that means, if my web-application client version is 1.2.3.4  it is compatible to server version 1.2.3.4

There are 1000 customers with let's say 1000 versions of server (yes, server release also happens with so many versions).

This web-application client gets released to production every two weeks with a newer version. Now, I can not keep all 1000 versions inside the android app as the size of the app will be out of control and release in production would be a mess.

Let us say that I have a mechanism with which I can find out customer's server version.

Can I download the web-application client package from one of our own server based on customer's server version and load it as a cordova app in mobile device ?

*We have tried to accommodate 10 web-application clients and tried converting them through cordova as an app but the size grew exponentially and we did not even have served many clients. That is a bottle-neck*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve desired functionality if you will use Cordova File Plugin. Main trick is to load files not from android_asset/www/app, but from location on the phone storage, using cdvfile protocol (which point to the file location on the phone SDcard).

1. When you application starts first time, you will go to you server and save latest app 
   version to the phone storage, and then launch you app logic code from there.
2. When you check for updates, you download new files to you app location and next time 
   application will use these files.

Comment: Actually when you say *When your application starts for the first time, you will go to your server and save latest app version to the phone storage*. 

That is exactly my question. How to fetch/download full web-application directory with contents on to the SD card or some location in mobile ? 

Can you please elaborate on that. And many thanks for the suggested approach.